Combining columns with different names but the same data
I have data in a data frame
> df.1
                Date1           Date2 Energy.kWh1 Energy.kWh2
2022-11-09 18:00            <NA>      152.227           NA
2022-11-09 19:00            <NA>      162.758           NA
2022-11-09 20:00            <NA>      159.078           NA
2022-11-09 21:00            <NA>      157.665           NA
2022-11-09 22:00            <NA>      157.346           NA
2022-11-09 23:00            <NA>      138.367           NA
2022-11-10 00:00            <NA>      129.780           NA
            <NA> 2022-12-01 1:00           NA      125.581
            <NA> 2022-12-01 2:00           NA      126.853
            <NA> 2022-12-01 3:00           NA      125.174
            <NA> 2022-12-01 4:00           NA      126.392

Date1 and Date2 columns are text, so using pmax is not appropriate.
I tried using if_else, but there is probably a more elegant solution
Expected output
> df.1
                Date Energy.kWh
2022-11-09 18:00        152.227
2022-11-09 19:00        162.758
2022-11-09 20:00        159.078
2022-11-09 21:00        157.665
2022-11-09 22:00        157.346
2022-11-09 23:00        138.367
2022-11-10 00:00        129.780
2022-12-01 01:00        125.581
2022-12-01 02:00        126.853
2022-12-01 03:00        125.174
2022-12-01 04:00        126.392


pmax can work with strings. with(quux, data.frame(Date = pmax(Date1, Date2, na.rm=TRUE), Energy = pmax(Energy.kWh1, Energy.kWh2, na.rm = TRUE))) is a base-R method for getting what you expect.
